# Employ a mergeFunction when adding an object to a set

Tags: java

I have a Java class `Foo`. `Foo` has two fields, `Integer bar` and `String baz`. I also have a set, `Set<Foo> foos`. When I run `foos.add(newFoo)`, if there is already an object in `foos` that is not "equal" to `newFoo` but has `bar` in common, instead of adding `newFoo` I want it to run a function `combine(Foo foo, Foo newFoo)` that updates the `foo` that's already in the set (say by adding the two `bar` values, or whatever). How can I best achieve this?

(the structure of `Foo`, the use of `Set`, etc. are not set in stone and can be changed to make for the best implementation)

Comment: Take a look at [`Map.merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

Comment: What have you ended up using?

Answer (score 0):

Given two `Set<Foo>`, using a `Stream<Foo>`, you can have

```
final Stream<Foo> combined = Stream.concat(setOne.stream(), setTwo.stream());
final Set<Foo> merged =
        combined.collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),
                Function.identity(),
                (foo, newFoo) -> {
                    // Your merge function
                    foo.baz += newFoo.baz;
                    return foo;
                }
        )).keySet();
```

You also need custom `equals` and `hashCode` methods, for example

```
public class Foo {
    public Integer bar;
    public String baz;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        final Foo foo = (Foo) o;
        return Objects.equals(bar, foo.bar);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(bar);
    }
}
```

If you cannot/don't want to customize the `Foo` class equality directly, you can create a wrapper class, e.g. `FooWrapper`, or you can *extend* the class.